# What's the default value of nullability annotation in Swift1.2

Tags: ios, swift

From Xcode 6.3 beta, it introduces nullability for Objective-C to ease interoperability between swift and oc, there seems to be four choice for that, which are nonnull,nullable,null_unspecified and null_resettable. They can both be applied to property,parameter and return type, but what is the default value if you don't specify. I guess is null_unspecified, but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All pointers are treated as `null_unspecified` unless you annotate otherwise. Once you start annotating, you'll start getting warnings on that class until you've annotated everything. You can change the default for a block of code to `nonnull` by using the new `#pragma` mark:

```objc
@interface MyObject : NSObject
#pragma clang assume_nonnull begin

// ...

#pragma clang assume_nonnull end
@end
```

Note that `null_resettable` can only be applied to properties, not parameters or return types. Its purpose is to allow properties to be reset by assigning them `nil`—the example from Apple is `tintColor`, which goes back to the default given a `nil` assignment.

Comment: Since null_unspecified is the default value,and in objective-c,many pointers tend to be nonnull,and apple recommends using audited regions in all objective-c headers,so in Xcode6.3 and above,the new pragma won't be tedious boilerplate?

Comment: Right, that's why they added the #pragma - you can basically mark your whole header as nonnull and then only annotate the nullable exceptions.